# Validation error messages are shown when user is typing instead of clicking submit button in AAD B2C custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Error message shows when the user is typing, not after user clicking submit button
[image]

I follow the instruction of how to add validation in claims from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policies-series-validate-user-input

However, when I use Restriction or PredicateValiation, the error message happens in realtime instead of after submission. My current workround is to use validation technical profile while this method is verbose as I need to implement individual techincal profile for each claim I want to hide error messages in realtime.

I noticed that in Microsoft live demo https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/unit-tests/blob/main/predicates/readme.md, the claim validation happens after submission. I'm not sure if it is due to pagelayout version or something else.

my code:

```xml
<DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.20</DataUri>

<ClaimType Id="newPassword">
    <DisplayName>Password</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>Enter password</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>Password</UserInputType>
    <PredicateValidationReference Id="SimplePassword" />
</ClaimType>

<PredicateValidation Id="SimplePassword">
  <PredicateGroups>
    <PredicateGroup Id="DisallowedWhitespaceGroup">
      <PredicateReferences>
        <PredicateReference Id="DisallowedWhitespace" />
      </PredicateReferences>
    </PredicateGroup>
    <PredicateGroup Id="AllowedAADCharactersGroup">
      <PredicateReferences>
        <PredicateReference Id="AllowedAADCharacters" />
      </PredicateReferences>
    </PredicateGroup>
        <PredicateGroup Id="LengthGroup">
      <PredicateReferences>
        <PredicateReference Id="IsLengthBetween8And128" />
      </PredicateReferences>
    </PredicateGroup>
</PredicateValidation>
```

I noticed that the old version does not have input pattern regex while 2.1.20 has. (Microsoft seems to have removed input pattern regex in 2.1.20 as well in the last two weeks) but the real-time validation error message is still persist

```xml
<input id="newPassword" class="textInput" type="password" placeholder="Password" title="Enter password" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true">
```

updated: for claims that do not have "required", there is no issue.

Comment: I've noticed that certain page layout versions have issues with Javascript and regex. You may want to try a different `Page Layout Version` in the `Page Layouts` of the flow and see if it resolves your issue on a previous page version.